how i can fix the tsconfig.json?
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ]
        }
        // ...
    }
}

Message found:

No inputs were found in config file
'c:/Users/Yubaa/gps-manage/frontend/tsconfig.json'. Specified
'include' paths were '["**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were '[]'.


What does your project look like? I am assuming you have files in the src directory?

in src i have assets, layouts, pages, router, app.css, app.jsx .... its a school-management project with laravel and react

Change the "@/*" value to

"src/*"

as the baseUrl defines the directory for non-relative module names.
Also, make sure to place this in root directory.
Also add include property, It will look for typescript files within the src directory,
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts" // You can adjust it as per path pattern of your project
  ]
}

